# stdout not working properly with linked assembly function in simple c program

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am trying to learn arm assembly currently, and I've been toying with blending c and asm together. What I made was a simple program that will enter an infinite loop (written in assembly) where a string is output to the console. The problem that I've run into is that the output when I run the assembly code by itself works as expected, but when I try to access the function from inside a C program, then the output is not the same as it was originally.

sample.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void loop();

int main (void){

        printf("Before loop:\n");
        loop();
        printf("After loop:\n");

}
```

assembly.s

```
.global loop

loop:
        MOV R0, #1
        LDR R1, =message
        LDR R2, =len
        MOV R7, #4
        SWI 0
        b loop

.data
message:
        .asciz "Hello from inside loop\n"

len = .-message
```

I compiled it as follows

```
as assembly.s -o assembly.o
ld assembly.o -o assembly
gcc sample.c assembly -o sample
./sample
Before loop:

^C
```

However when I run the asm by itself, it runs without issue. Anyone have a second to explain this to me?

```
    ./assembly
    Before loop:
    Hello from inside loop
    Hello from inside loop
    Hello from inside loop
    Hello from inside loop
    ^C
```

EDIT: for clarification, there was a long string of unicode characters after the C version of the program, that were filtered out of this post. It was not the appropriate output but there was an infinite string of some character.

Comment: I am surprised that even worked. You need to link the object file not the executable. So do `gcc sample.c assembly.o -o sample`. Note `gcc` can invoke the assembler for you so can do it in one step: `gcc sample.c assembly.s -o sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Jester stated in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000692/stdout-not-working-properly-with-linked-assembly-function-in-simple-c-program/73001071#comment128934430_73000692), the answer is that I was not compiling correctly:

> You need to link the object file not the executable. So do
>
> ```
> gcc sample.c assembly.o -o sample
> ```
>
> Note `gcc` can invoke the assembler for you so can do it in one step:
>
> ```
> gcc sample.c assembly.s -o sample
> ```